# Why is there a vertical line inside the frame?

Tags: plotting

I would like to present two similar codes here.
The first one returns a graph with a vertical line inside the frame,but the second one doesn't.

```
Plot[z^2, {z, 7.5, 8.4}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
Plot[z^2, {z, 7.4, 8.4}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesOrigin.html) which is set by default to [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) and sometimes misfires.

Try for instance

```
Plot[z^2, {z, 7.5, 8.4}, Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {8, 60}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

To turn it off:

```
Plot[z^2, {z, 7.5, 8.4}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]